# Which programming languages support posix-based regular expressions?

Tags: regex, posix-ere

I know about re module in Python but it does not follow posix standard and PHP has removed ereg. Is there any library in any language which supports that? I think the closest is regex library in Java. Anyone knows about another? 
What would be the closest to use regular expressions such as those used in egrep in linux?

Comment: Most languages are moving in the direction of PCRE, not POSIX regexp. There's even a `-P` option to GNU grep that uses PCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try regex library in python i think you can get posix-based regular expressions if you use POSIX flag. Here some documentation https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/